# How do I force CiviMail to process all mail as an email activity?

Tags: civimail, joomla

[image]I've setup CiviMail to process inbound mail as activities and assigns those emails to contacts.

My problem is CiviMail does not process ALL emails. The component set up an "ignored" and "processed" folder. Everything in the "ignored" folder does not show up in CiviCRM as an activity. Everything in the "processed" folder does show up as an activity and is assigned to a contact.

How do I force CiviMail to process ALL mail? Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Ignored usually means something went wrong during processing. Is there something unusual about those emails? Does the cron job log show any errors?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Nothing unusual and no errors. Some of the emails are returned emails that were ignored, but previous emails (the same day, same thread) from the same individual were processed.

Comment: Where does the output from your cron job go? There should be something in there any time it puts something in the ignored folder. When you say "returned emails" do you mean regular replies or bounce notices? Bounce notices do get ignored.

Comment: To clarify: When I mentioned returned emails I was speaking of emails sent to me by an individual after I've contacted them. For example: I send an email, the recipient replies (this email is processed by CiviMail), I send them a response, recipient replies to my email (this is what I am calling a returned email and it is ignored by CiviMail). I added a screenshot to my original post of the Activity Job cron log from CiviMail for your review.

Comment: What causes an email to bounce?

Comment: By bounce I meant the email address is wrong to begin with, so no I see you're saying these are replies from people. For the output, thanks just I'm not sure that's what I'm looking for. Normally you have a cron script that is scheduled via your hosting panel or you set up manually through ssh, and its output goes somewhere, either to an email addresses or is redirected to a file. In some control panels the default is to just discard all output and you need to specify what to do with it.

Comment: My cron job: php/home/path/public_html/itknw.com/iRstone/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php -u username -p password -e Job -a execute Here is the output from the last email received after the cron job ran. Although I have my cron jobs set up to run every hour at 0 and 30. Not exactly sure why I don't get an email every time it runs.                                                                  Output: Processed as Activity: Weekly Newsletter
Processed as Activity: NPMC- Program Planning & Board Governance

Comment: Hmm, yeah if there were errors it should appear in those emails. At this point I'd suggest either posting at https://chat.civicrm.org in the user-support channel, or engaging the services of someone at https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors. I understand if you can't post the full details of the ignored emails here on a public site, so I'm out of ideas otherwise.

Comment: I don't see any results from the cron job of the ignored emails. Just the processed ones. I will try the support channel. Thank you for your time.